# Group json data based on one attribute on querying couchbase

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

I can retrive the below data in couchbase using query.

select distinct SupplierName, Currency, CountryOfOrigin 
    from `RangePlan` where type = "Supplier"

[{
     "CountryOfOrigin": "China",
     "currency": "USD",
     "supplierName": "abc"
    },

{
     "CountryOfOrigin": "China",
     "currency": "USD",
     "supplierName": "bcd"
      },

{
    "CountryOfOrigin": "India",
     "currency": "USD",
     "supplierName": "hij"
    },

{
     "CountryOfOrigin": "India",
     "currency": "USD",
     "supplierName": "klm"
    }]

Now I need help in getting the data based on the Country of Origin as below.

```
{ 
 "china" : [ 
  { 
    "supplierName" : "abc", 
    "currency" : "USD" 
  } ,
  { 
    "supplierName" : "bcd", 
    "currency" : "USD" 
  } 
] 
 } 
  "india" : [ 
{ 
    "supplierName" : "hij", 
    "currency" : "INR" 
  } ,
  { 
    "supplierName" : "klm", 
    "currency" : "INR" 
  }     
  ] 
}
```

I need a query to the above output.

Thanks,
Emraan

Answer (score 1):

SELECT RAW OBJECT v.CountryOfOrigin: v.val FOR v IN
             (SELECT q.CountryOfOrigin , ARRAY_AGG({"currency":q.Currency,"supplierName":q.SupplierName}) val FROM
                   (SELECT DISTINCT SupplierName, Currency, CountryOfOrigin from RangePlan WHERE type = "Supplier") As q
             GROUP BY q.CountryOfOrigin) END;